# ICAL Calendar Import/Export Sync like Airbnb

Tags: import, calendar, export, synchronization, icalendar

How can I get the same architecture Airbnb is using for their ICAL calendar Import/Export sync. It seems like all the booking sites have it now 9flats, wimdu, roomarama, Vaway. I would like to know what they are using becasue it seems to be same standard architecture on all the sites. how do I get this script or service. See link below it describes it. Im using wd calendar a google calendar clone (Jquery, Ajax) on my site right now. I need to import Ical calendars Via link and export calendar via ics url.

http://www.tnooz.com/2011/07/29/news/how-a-uk-startup-fixed-the-airbnb-calendar-availability-problem-without-being-asked/

Comment: Have you found answer on your question because I am curious about it too?